# SSRS - column calculations

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, reporting-services

In SQL Server Reporting Services within Visual Studio, I created a  report which has a detail and a total line.  I try to subtract the value in the total line from the value in the detail line and I get a result of Zero which is incorrect.  See example below :

```
                 Col A                      Col B                      

Detail            4.7                      4.7 – 4.0
lines             3.7                      3.7 – 4.0
                  3.5                      3.5 – 4.0

Total/AVG         4.0
```

In Column B, I take the figure from detail line in col A and subtract the Total line from it and get zero instead of 0.7 etc....

Comment: How do your calculations go? For example are you using FieldX-Sum(FieldX)? Give an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to include the scope for the calculating the average within your detail row. If you are doing this at the group level, aggregate on the table's group:

```
=Fields!MyField.Value - AVG(Fields!MyField.Value, "table1_Group1")
```

If it is at the dataset level, you can do the same with the dataset:

```
=Fields!MyField.Value - AVG(Fields!MyField.Value, "MyDataset")
```